# Is AWS Elasticsearch is completely managed service or is it just a Elasticsearch installation on set of ec2 instance

Tags: aws, elasticsearch

I want to understand the difference between AWS Elasticsearch service vs on-premise version. Does AWS provides a fully managed service for Elasticsearch (like DynamoDB, SQS etc) Do we have to manage at the node level and ensure that Elasticsearch has proper configuration for production kind of environment?
Appreciate your feedback on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a managed service operated by AWS.

That being said I'd look at https://cloud.elastic.co/ which can run on AWS, GCP and Azure. 14 days for free. It's managed by elastic, creator of elasticsearch.

Cloud by elastic is one way to have access to all features, all managed by us. Think about what is there yet like Security, Monitoring, Reporting, SQL, Canvas, APM, Logs UI, Infra UI, SIEM, Maps UI and what is coming next :) ...

Disclaimer: I'm an elastic employee.

Comment: Thanks @dadoonet for your reply. May I know what is the difference between AWS Elasticsearch service vs https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01N6YCISK?ref=_ptnr_elastic_ec_pricing_faq

And if AWS Elasticsearch service is managed service by AWS, why do we have to worry about the number of nodes, node types etc? Appreciate your help to clarify on this. thanks

Comment: Sure. Read https://www.elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service#full-comparison